# How to add dependencies to a windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, dependencies, installshield

How to add dependencies to a windows service in InstallShield?
My winservice depend on the two following services, so they must run before the service starts:

1. COMSysApp
2. SENS

Note: I have used InstallShield project to install my service and not windows installer class so i could not use the way that mr. Jerry.Wang suggested in [his article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23176/Create-a-system-tray-icon-and-a-dialog-for-a-Windo?msg=4375864#xx4375864xx).

**EDIT:**

How to add a dependency to SEN Service in installshield?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95615/cross-posting-etiquette

Comment: @ChristopherPainter, Yes i know, and because of this i am too confusing. but when i asked Mr. Wang how can i define dependencies of my service, he just answered "your service depends on SENS, which should be started before your service".however i could not find any exe file for SENS or COMSysApp???

Comment: In reading the article linked above, the issue is a dependency on the System Event Notification Service (SENS) which needs to be started (using svchost) before the target service can run.

Comment: @kdmurray,Thanks for your reply, can you please describe what is svchost?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svchost

Comment: FWIW it takes 2 basic skills to be able to create really good installers (or anything for that matter).  1) An understanding of what needs to be done 2) An understanding of how to make it happen.  #1 has to come before #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself by adding the dependencies in ServiceComponent Wizard.

Answer (score 2):

If you have dependencies on other services, the [ServiceInstall table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has the Dependencies column to describe this:

> This column is a list of names of services or load ordering groups
>   that the system must start before this service. Separate names in the
>   list by Nulls. If the service has no dependencies, then specify Null
>   or an empty string. Use the syntax [~] to insert a Null. Dependency on
>   a group means that this service can run if at least one member of the
>   group is running after an attempt to start all members of the group.
>
> For example, to require that the system start service1 and service2,
>   before starting the service listed in the ServiceInstall column, enter
>   service1[~]service2[~][~] into the Dependencies column. The
>   identifiers service1 and service2 must either occur in the primary key
>   of the table or be the name of the service that is already installed.
>
> You must prefix group names with + so that they can be distinguished
>   from a service name. To require that the system start service1 and at
>   least one member of the ordering group MyGroup before starting the
>   service listed in the ServiceInstall column, enter
>   service1[~]+MyGroup[~][~].

Here is what InstallShield has to say about their representation of that table:

[Services Settings](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/ComponentControlNT.htm#wp1183582)

Enter any service or load-ordering groups that this service requires. The system attempts to start the dependent service or at least one member of the load-ordering group before starting this service.

Separate multiple dependencies with a comma (,).

> You must precede the name of each load-ordering group with the
>   SC_GROUP_IDENTIFIER—which is typically the plus sign (+)—so that the
>   Service Control Manager can distinguish it from a service.

Comment: I have already tried this way and added dependencies to dependency property of ServiceComponent after create it,but it does not work! However when i added them in ServiceComponent wizard, they successfully was added as dependencies of the service!!?