# How to form dependency between 2 windows services

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have 2 windows services, ServiceA and ServiceB.

I would like to know how can I start ServiceA first and then start ServiceB when ServiceA is on interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service dependencies is exactly what you need. If ServiceA depends on ServiceB, it will be started only after ServiceB entered the running state.

If you need to add dependency to the service you're developing, first [add service installer to the project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then use it's `ServicesDependedOn` property to specify services that should be started before yours.

If you need to modify dependency of installed service, use command line (or programmatically run the command):

```
sc config [service name] depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
```

Answer (score 0):

If ServiceA has a dependency on ServiceB, the latter will be started when starting ServiceA.

If your question is *"**How** to add a dependency to another service"*, see [create dependency between windows services startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159257/create-dependency-between-windows-services-startup), [How to add dependencies to a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580353/how-to-add-dependencies-to-a-windows-service).